# Commercial OSM Overpass server

Tags: overpass-api

I am looking for a reliable hosted Overpass server where I can pay for N requests per sec/hour/day. I looked at https://switch2osm.org/providers/, and https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/List_of_OSM-based_services , and googled, but did not find any. I found several for geocoding (Nominatim), but nobody offers overpass API. Public servers have low limits for use and not very reliable.

Comment: [Commercial OSM Software and Services](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Commercial_OSM_Software_and_Services) has a number of companies offering services in the OSM space, though I'm not sure which ones would actually host an Overpass instance for you.